# How do I work around the N+1 issue with one-to-one mapping in NHibernate?

Tags: performance, nhibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I have a Task entity which has a preceding and following task:

```
namespace OneToOneIssue.Domain
{
    public class Task
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Task FollowingTask { get; set; }
        public virtual Task PrecedingTask { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task](
    [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [Description] nvarchar(100) NULL,
    [FollowingTaskId] uniqueidentifier NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('30efbfda-f3b5-42fb-906e-098fb32be79d', 'Task 1', 'f7367187-406d-47db-931e-b9e4fa8a4774')
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('f7367187-406d-47db-931e-b9e4fa8a4774', 'Task 2', '42c25da5-7c04-4adc-a9c2-6bf8a9ff5c89')
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('42c25da5-7c04-4adc-a9c2-6bf8a9ff5c89', 'Task 3', NULL)
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('ffe58f51-bb85-4681-af9d-d232326a30e4', 'Task 4', 'ba2ee26c-ebbb-4d7e-a596-40db9f0711c4')
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('ba2ee26c-ebbb-4d7e-a596-40db9f0711c4', 'Task 5', '29189134-8be9-4d93-873e-ce5efefe1c1a')
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('29189134-8be9-4d93-873e-ce5efefe1c1a', 'Task 6', NULL)
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('ef069d0a-f2a8-4c9a-8bbc-99ee1e0e2991', 'Task 7', '56a6eb57-ab9f-49cb-875a-a072158b0265')
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('56a6eb57-ab9f-49cb-875a-a072158b0265', 'Task 8', 'f8b7cc9b-269e-44c7-85bf-44592d70a21e')
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Description], [FollowingTaskId]) VALUES ('f8b7cc9b-269e-44c7-85bf-44592d70a21e', 'Task 9', NULL)
```

and the mapping like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               namespace="OneToOneIssue.Domain"
               assembly="OneToOneIssue.Domain">
  <class name="Task" table="`Task`">
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="guid">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" column="`Description`" />
    <many-to-one name="FollowingTask" class="Task" column="FollowingTaskId" />
    <one-to-one name="PrecedingTask" class="Task" property-ref="FollowingTask" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now if I run a query to get tasks 2, 5 and 8 (the only ones that have a preceding and following task like this:

```
var tasks = session
                .CreateCriteria<Task>()
                .Add(Restrictions.In("Description", new string[] {"Task 2", "Task 5", "Task 8"}))
                .List<Task>();
```

Then I get the main query I would expect but also a query each for all of the preceding tasks:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT this_.Id as Id0_1_, this_.[Description] as Descript2_0_1_, this_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_1_, task2_.Id as Id0_0_, task2_.[Description] as Descript2_0_0_, task2_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_0_ FROM [Task] this_ left outer join [Task] task2_ on this_.Id=task2_.FollowingTaskId WHERE this_.[Description] in (@p0, @p1, @p2)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Task 2',@p1=N'Task 5',@p2=N'Task 8'
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT task0_.Id as Id0_1_, task0_.[Description] as Descript2_0_1_, task0_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_1_, task1_.Id as Id0_0_, task1_.[Description] as Descript2_0_0_, task1_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_0_ FROM [Task] task0_ left outer join [Task] task1_ on task0_.Id=task1_.FollowingTaskId WHERE task0_.FollowingTaskId=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='FFE58F51-BB85-4681-AF9D-D232326A30E4'
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT task0_.Id as Id0_1_, task0_.[Description] as Descript2_0_1_, task0_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_1_, task1_.Id as Id0_0_, task1_.[Description] as Descript2_0_0_, task1_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_0_ FROM [Task] task0_ left outer join [Task] task1_ on task0_.Id=task1_.FollowingTaskId WHERE task0_.FollowingTaskId=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='EF069D0A-F2A8-4C9A-8BBC-99EE1E0E2991'
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT task0_.Id as Id0_1_, task0_.[Description] as Descript2_0_1_, task0_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_1_, task1_.Id as Id0_0_, task1_.[Description] as Descript2_0_0_, task1_.FollowingTaskId as Followin3_0_0_ FROM [Task] task0_ left outer join [Task] task1_ on task0_.Id=task1_.FollowingTaskId WHERE task0_.FollowingTaskId=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='30EFBFDA-F3B5-42FB-906E-098FB32BE79D'
```

I don't even need the preceding task loaded.

Eager loading the preceding task does not help either.

It does not help if I set the FollowingTask and PrecedingTask to lazy="proxy". It does solve the problem if remove the one-to-one mapping, but this is not a possible solution.

I have seen questions on here about getting round the problem if you need the mapped one-to-one and the answer seems to be that it's a bug and you just have to live with it. However, I do not even need it loaded. I never access it, it just loads for no reason. I believe this question is also unique because of the recursive nature of the relationship.

Is there any way I can prevent it loading or is there another way altogether to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, how to change the mapping. The table structure fits to *parent-child* schema. We only know that you'd like to have exactly *one* child.

For *parent-child* has NHibernate strong support and you won't experience loading of related children any more. So, Instead of `<ont-to-one` map it like this. c#:

```
public class Task
{
  public virtual Task FollowingTask { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Task> PrecedingTasks { get; set; }
}
```

mapping hbm:

```
<many-to-one name="FollowingTask" class="Task" column="FollowingTaskId" />
<bag name="PrecedingTasks">
   <key column="FollowingTaskId"></key>
   <one-to-many class="Task"/>
</bag>
```

Now we can even make the `IList<Task> PrecedingTasks` protected and create `Task PrecedingTask` property which will handle the *get/set* access to the first `PrecedingTasks` list element

Comment: Cheers, but this changes the model, it is not a parent-child relationship. A task has one and only one preceding task. I have modelled a parent-child relationship many times before and you're right, it does not have the same issue.

Comment: Do not get me wrong. But there is a column `FollowingTaskId`. So it is a parent of current record. (it is reverted in your model, but please, take a deeper look). Each (in this case one and only) child can be find searching current `Id` in others `FollowingTaskId`. So, in an abstract way, the Table structure is parent child. with a very deep tree of single child and child and child...  If you will Access from *Virtual* property PrecedingTask the first element, you will gain profit from both worlds

Comment: Single child policy, a bit like China? :) Maybe the _precedingTasks collection could be private, and have a PrecedingTask property, where the set replaces the only record, and the get returns _precedingTasks.FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: Exactly that's my point. Single child policy is your business rule. The mapping is ready to have more of them. But as I said, if the virtual/unmapped property `PrecidingTask` (no *s* at the end) would manipulate with protected list of `PrecidingTasks` ... you will gain a lot. And as I said, from both worlds ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit of a hack, but it does seem to be a known bug, and bugs require work arounds. This all works well and will have minimal impact on the codebase and database. I have written it up on my blog: http://lucidcoding.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/overcomming-n1-issue-with-one-to-one.html

Comment: Great if that helped! Nice blog post ;)